# Do you have any tips to improve ReSharper and/or Visual Studio performance?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, performance, resharper

I'm using visual studio 2008 and [ReSharper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReSharper) 4 and it's kind of slow. My machine has 2 GB of RAM, dual core processor and a 7200 rpm hard disk. I know more RAM and a faster hard disk could improve performance, but do you have any tips to improve ReSharper/Visual Studio performance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Turn off the annoying RSS reader**

- Tools, Options, Environment, Startup

**Turn off all the animations**

- Tools, Options, Environment, Animate Environment Tools

**Install the [recent Service Pack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/products/cc533447.aspx)**

**Clean out your WebCache**

- AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebSiteCache

Answer (score 5):

Visual Studio optimisations:  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440/visual-studio-optimizations#8453](https://web.archive.org/web/20121018012709/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440/visual-studio-optimizations)

**Edit:**
The above SO post has unfortunately been deleted and is replaced with a web archive link.

Microsoft have [provided some tips](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-studio-performance-tips-and-tricks) that essentially boil down to turning off features you don't need and reducing solution size by splitting up a solution into smaller self contained solutions where appropriate.

JetBrains has also [provided an article](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Speeding_Up_ReSharper.html) that list a whole range of tweaks you can make to both Resharper settings and Visual Studio settings to improve performance.

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 3):

- Disable unused extensions under "Tools - Extensions".
- Disable "Track
  changes" in "Tools - Options - Text Editor".
- Disable "Rich client
  visual experience" in the "Options - Environment".
- Disable
  IntelliTrace (Ultimate edition only) - in the "Tools - Options -
  IntelliTrace - General"
- Disable "Track Active items" - "Tools -
  Options - Projects and Solutions - Track Active Item in Solution
  Explorer".
- Disable ReSharper IntelliSense in the ReSharper options
- Disable ReSharper "Analyse errors in whole solution"
- Disable editing
  enhancements in ReSharper - in ReSharper options turn off all the
  boxes under "Options - Environment - Editor"

This is a snippet from [this](http://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/218-visual-studio--resharper-performance-tips/) blog-post

Answer (score 2):

Having too many projects within your solution also appears to be a factor when it comes to performance. I have no real evidence of this but from my experience, less projects equates to better performance.

If consolidating projects is not an option then create an alternate solution file so you can add only the existing projects that are relevant to the work you are doing.

Comment: This also cuts down on the benefits of refactoring though.  If your product is all built within a single location, having a single solution allows you to make massive refactorings very easy.  Instead opening each one and making the required changes is a royal PITA.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same issue, and from the JetBrains site, it looks like they sort-of know about it but aren't admitting anything. Turning off solution-wide analysis does seem to help quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Mainly open Visual Studio options (Tools | Options) and configure the preferences as follows:

**Environment | General: disable Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance, disable Enable rich client visual experience, enable Use hardware graphics acceleration if available.** These adjustments will reduce UI lags and improve overall performance.

Please read this official turtial:
[Speed up ReSharper (and Visual Studio)](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Speeding_Up_ReSharper.html)