# ReSharper-- Unstable for anybody else?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I have seen Jetbrain's ReSharper tool on many "must-have" tool lists. I've installed it on a few occasions over the last few years and it's turned my Visual Studio sluggish and erratic. I generally uninstall it after a week or two because it make VS flaky, I want to like it, but I can't get past the instability.

So what's the deal? Am I having bad luck? Does the tool have issues but the usefulness out weighs the issues? Anyone else out there have trouble with it? Are there some troublesome options to turn off?

Answer (score 2):

These previously asked questions should help in answering your **duplicate** question:

- [Do you have any tips to improve
  resharper and/or visual studio
  performance ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23737/do-you-have-any-tips-to-improve-resharper-andor-visual-studio-performance)
- [ReSharper sluggishness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84009/resharper-sluggishness)

Answer (score 1):

The one thing that I have seen that makes VS slow when R# is on is the lack of RAM and a slow CPU.

That being said, the only time I see slowness is when working in VB.  C# is blazing fast ALL the time.  The current computer I have isn't as good as my last one, but it does have 2GB of RAM and dual core P4 (3.20GHz).

Things that CAN slow R# down though are:

- Solution Errors setting
- Code that has lots and lots and lots of errors
- Code that has lots of analysis errors
- Code Rush installed as well

Comment: What do you mean by the Solution Errors Setting?  output verbosity? Or is this a resharper setting?

Comment: Solution Errors setting is a setting in R# that displays all the errors, in all the files, that R# sees.  It can hog the CPU.

Answer (score 1):

I keep having the same issues.  Performance is fine really but my machine has 6gb of memory and a quad core processor.  It is the constant system hangs, unit test running hangs, visual studio crashing when opening solutions etc that has meant I uninstalled it.  I do have Vista Business 64 but every other add on and program I have work fine.  If I uninstall resharper 4.1 everything starts working again.

There again, it behaved in the same way on my dual core laptop too.

Visual Assist X seems rock solid in comparison but it does not have as many features (it is half the price though).
Ste

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced a lot of what you're talking about over the years as well, but I have to say having recently moved to the 4.0 version of ReSharper, a lot of that overhead has been cut down dramatically and it seems to be quite a bit more functional to boot.

Try it again. What's the worst that can happen? You'll uninstall it again? No big loss.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I've found remotely sluggish about it is right-clicking anything.

The context menu strip takes ages to load, but the time i lose right-clicking anything is far less compared to the time it saves me refactoring.